# Adding elements to arrays with different names using a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, hashmap

I have the following ArrayLists.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> RP1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> RP2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

I want to add a HashMap to each ArrayList in a loop. Currently I am adding them like so:

```
RP1.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
RP1.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
RP2.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
RP2.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
```

Is there any way to do this with a for loop? My current method seems inefficient.

Comment: Wait **why** do you want to do this?

Comment: It is inefficient when you add HashMap that is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as efficiency goes, an unrolled loop like you posted will be faster than any loop construct. If you are more interested in conciseness and have more than two variables, you might consider declaring an `ArrayList` of `List<Map<Integer, Integer>>` rather than separate variables. I also recommend that you [program to an interface](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciplesP.html) (declare all your variables as interface types [e.g., `List`] rather than implementation types [`ArrayList`]):

```
List<List<Map<Integer, Integer>>> RPs = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ARRAYLISTS; i++) {
    List<Map<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_MAPS_PER_LIST; j++) {
        list.add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
    }
    RPs.add(list);
}
```

If you really need to access each `List<Map<Integer, Integer>>` by name, but still want to eliminate the individual variables, then declare the outer structure as a `Map<String, List<Map<Integer, Integer>>` and add the elements by name that way. But none of this is going to make things more efficient, just (perhaps) easier to program.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. didn't test it.

```
example(RP1,RP2); 
/* or example(RP1,RP1,RP2,RP2) */


public static void example(ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> ... arrays){

      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
           arrays[i].add(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
}
```

more info:https://today.java.net/article/2004/04/13/java-tech-using-variable-arguments